# How to notify the user that visiting website has PWA application using javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking into Progressive Web App(PWA) and had some code - which is working fine. Here, i want to notify the users  - visiting website has PWA  and ask for installation of PWA application via alert box. If user click yes then PWA installed on device.

What i look into - [Youtube Udemy tutorial for PWA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3jTvWj8JrQ&t=158s). I searched into google but found nothing

Comment: According to - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android#action you could not do so.

Answer (score 0):

PWA default characteristics is to pop up and ask for PWA installation thus there is no need of alert box.If you configure your service worker

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

and

> manifest.json

correct it will be enough.
Example:

```
{
  "short_name": "AirHorner",
  "name": "Kinlan's AirHorner of Infamy",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-1x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html?launcher=true"
}
```

[please refer the link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/)